# Error on sending mail using Windows application

Tags: windows, vb.net, telerik

In my system, I'm using a windows application project. While I'm sending a mail from the project I get an error as **"Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {20C62CA0-15DA-101B-B9A8-444553540000} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error:80040112 Class is not licensed for use (Exception from HRResult: 0x800401120)."**. Can you please help me with the fix for this? I'm using Windows 10 OS.

```
Dim oMAPSession As New MSMAPI.MAPISession <br/>
Dim MAPIMessages As New MSMAPI.MAPIMessages

Do While J > 0
      With MAPIMessages
        oMAPSession.SignOn()
        .SessionID = oMAPSession.SessionID
        .Compose()

        If attachbio Then
            .AttachmentIndex = 0
            If CustomTable.GetCustomNumber("TEPrintPerUser") = 1 Then
                .AttachmentPathName = g_fpReportsPath & "\tempbio.pdf"
            Else
                .AttachmentPathName = Application.StartupPath & "\tempbio.pdf"
            End If
            .AttachmentName = "techbio.pdf"
        End If

        strRecip = Trim(rdtxtFldNumber.Text)
        i = 0
        Do
            .RecipIndex = i
            .RecipType = 1

            If InStr(1, strRecip, ";") > 0 Then
                .RecipDisplayName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(strRecip, InStr(1, strRecip, ";") - 1)
                strRecip = Mid(strRecip, InStr(1, strRecip, ";") + 1)
                i = i + 1
            Else
                If (strRecip <> "") Then
                    .RecipDisplayName = strRecip
                End If
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        GetDispatchForm = New FrmDispatch
        If g_sidCustomization = "Nebrasky" And GetDispatchForm.rdddlText.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            .MsgSubject = Replace(rdtxtfpSubject.Text, Chr(10), " ")
        Else
            .MsgSubject = "Text Message " & Date.Now
        End If

        If tmpTextCapacity <= 0 Or (Not IsNumeric(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(.RecipDisplayName, InStr(1, .RecipDisplayName, "@") - 1))) Then
            .MsgNoteText = strText
            J = 0
        Else
            .MsgNoteText = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(strText, tmpTextCapacity)
        End If               
        .Send()                
    End With
    strText = Mid(strText, tmpTextCapacity + 1)
    J = J - tmpTextCapacity
Loop
```

[image]

Comment: Any chance showing us the code you're using to send the email?  Please update your question with the relevant info.

Comment: Added the code for your reference. Please check and do the needful. Thanks

Comment: And, where exactly do you get the error?  Have you got Outlook installed and configured correctly?

Comment: I get this issue while sending the email. Yes i have installed correctly.

Comment: So, the errors specifically on the .send() line?

Comment: yes. correct. i guess it may be during SignOn() or oMAPSession.SessionID as 0. but am not sure with it.

Comment: i am not able to debug the issue on the client environment as it is a build file.

Comment: So, to clarify it works as expected on your development machine?

Comment: Yes. this code is working in my development machine. but my OS is windows 7.

Comment: Is there any update regarding this issue? Can you please check and help with this?

Comment: Team : Awaiting for an update

Comment: The problem is likely the machine you’re deploying to.  Could any environmental issue, Anything like corrupt  outlook install, UAT restrictions, security software user mailbox issue.  As it’s not really a problem with your code as it runs as expected on your dev computer, probably a little outside the scope of what we can help with